# Thread.sleep vs Timers

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

So in my research I have found these main differences between using a timer to execute an instruction and executing an instruction then making the thread sleep.

## Observe the following code

```
public class StkFlow {
    public void event(ActionEvent e){
        //do some stuff
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Timer tick=new Timer (200, event);
        tick.start ();
    }
}
```

## AND

```
public class StkFlow {
    public static void main (String[] args){
    while (/*Condition*/){
        //Do some stuff
        Thread.sleep (200);
    }
}
```

The first piece of code uses a timer and executes some code every 200ms and the second piece of code executes some code and puts the thread to sleep for 200ms.The difference is that the timer already iterates for you and does not pause the thread unlike Thread.sleep which stops all processing,(the subject here is the timer) so what if you had a loop inside it, and what if this loop was comparing identical objects? Would it keep creating a new instance of this loop?, and if it does what is the end result, say,  if it was processing some heavy duty instructions in that loop?

> E.G

```
public class StkFlow {
    public void event(ActionEvent e){
        while (0==0){   
            //do some heavy duty stuff
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Timer tick=new Timer (200, event);
        tick.start ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how this code is related to Java ...

Comment: The difference is that sleep() prevents the thread to do anything. If you were doing that from the swing event dispatch thread, for example, the UI would be completely irresponsive, frozen. For how a Time deals with long tasks, read the javadoc. That's what it's for.

Comment: I didnt ask what it was for, the question is clearly stated at the bottom

Comment: *"Because it is written in java smartass"* No it is not.

Comment: This is clearly java,if you think it isnt prove it then.

Comment: It is clearly Java? Java doesn't has the keywords `Public` or `While`. You were able to fix the first one, congratulation, but the second is still wrong.

Comment: So ur gonna waste time on the capital P and the capital W

Comment: If you think that your question is a waste of time, then why do you ask it?

Comment: Sigh. Guys, this is not constructive to say the least. OP: JB Nizet is right - to understand how `Timer` handles long processing, you simply have to read the documentation of `Timer`.

Comment: So you are marking down my question why?

Comment: Being aggressive and rude towards everybody who comments/answers on your question is an easy way to earn yourself downvotes. Do you want your question answered or do you want to argue and bicker? Seems it's the latter.

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer Please read SO rules in [help]. There are not robotic and lifeless and will let you post questions that will yield more constructive response.

Comment: Am I the one who started this? The capital letters were a typo and all of those people were being antagonistic.

Comment: How do you think **I** feel.

Comment: Yes, you were the one who started all of this. The comments may have felt pedantic and pointless but these details matter when coding *and* these people were totally correct. Instead of just explaining the situation and fixing your question, you started name calling and throwing a tantrum. That's not very constructive. It's hard to help when you aren't showing us the *actual* code you're working with, especially when your code doesn't even compile (and your claimed issue is run-time, not compile-time).

Comment: Okay whatevs, im done.Its just that I havent had a good experience here and its not getting better.Always redirecting me to the javadocs, I know it is there but I asked because I didnt want to go there.The question I am proposing is theoretical and I dont have ACTUAl code, because there is nothing to fix I just want some insight.

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer Try being more receptive to feedback? If you react this way every time you get a negative response because of a poorly written question, you're not going to have a good time here. Just take the time to write your question out more carefully and listen when people are trying to help your question make sense. Also, if you haven't bothered to read the documentation, and the question you asked can be answered by it, why would you be surprised if people tell you to go read the documentation? *All* programmers are expected to do that in the very least.

Comment: Okay I get your point but it didnt seem like they were trying to help, like saying "why are you asking us? Go read that over there and stop wasting my time"

Comment: That still doesnt mean they should mark down my questions, its just bullying I could have went below 0

Comment: There seems to be some mild pedantry in regards to syntactically incorrect code and only one person told you to read the documentation. I think you are being overly sensitive. You responded in an extremely aggressive and rude manner so I'm not sure why you're so appalled when people respond similarly. If you'd like further discussion about how your question can be improved and to raise issues about how this was handled by the community, please post over on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer It's not "bullying". People have the right to vote depending on how useful they think the question is, period. And no, you can never drop below 0. You got lots of feedback on how to improve your question, but *you chose* to "fight back" instead. When you come to a new place, it's rudimentary that you learn what rules are commonly followed, instead of expecting that everyone will do what you want, the way you want. People here are really willing to help, just play by the rules :-)

Comment: @BartoszKP I did improve my question fyi, every single time I got a comment in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thread.sleep which stops all processing, so what if you had a loop inside it, and what if this loop was comparing identical objects? Would it keep creating a new instance of this loop?, and if it does what is the end result, say, if it was processing some heavy duty instructions in that loop?

no, it won't, you need to `start()` a new thread. `Thread.sleep()` stops the current thread, but if you run it in its own thread then it will not stop the main thread and each task you may run in its own thread, tho they could start after the time ticks.

Comment: Im talking about the timer really

Comment: But I'm talking about your question.

Comment: Okay, sorry let me post an example of what I mean

Comment: Oh that sorry, ill go fix that, im in a rush kind of.

Comment: No I dont, I am using the current thread there is no need for that

Comment: You also misundertood the subject of tha sentence

Comment: Naturally I dont think a timer can wait for code to be completed, as it is a timer.So o asked what if every 200ms it called an unending loop.

Comment: It will stop the current thread until you run the code inside the loop in the separate thread.

Comment: But if it stops then how is it a timer?, since it waits and does NOT execute the code every 200ms

Comment: It waits 200ms, but the code is executing parallel.

Comment: I understand that the timer creates a thread, what I dont get is if it creates a new thread each time since the loop does not end.You said it stops the current thread so how can it wait?

Comment: you can specify a condition to end the loop, but the program will continue to run until all threads finish or you shutdown them properly. It wakes up after the 200ms and breaks in to the loop.

Comment: Okay.(it says it needs more characters)