# Android: what are the pros and cons of using a CountDownTimer vs Thread.sleep()?

Tags: android, multithreading, countdowntimer

**What I want to do:**

I am wanting to use a worker-thread to regularly update a textfield in the UI Thread. Let's say, every 2 seconds for 30 seconds. I need the 30 second countdown to happen even if the app is not on the foreground. For now, I am evaluating the merits of two different approaches (both using worker-threads) in implementing this. I won't post the full code here to simplify things and also because I am not asking to find any problem in my code. Both solutions work fine.

**Solution #1 - use `Thread.sleep()` inside a `for` loop**

```
for (int i = 30; i > 0; i-=2) {
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_ID, i, 0);
    msg.sendToTarget();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        // catch error
    }

}
```

**Solution #2 - use `CountDownTimer`**

```
Looper.prepare()

new CountDownTimer(30000, 2000) {
    public void onTick(long millUntilFinish) {
        int seconds = (int)(millUntilFinish);
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_ID, seconds, 0);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // left blank for now
    }
}.start();

Looper.loop();
```

**My Question**

While both work, I am wanting to know if there is a "better" or a "preferred" way to do it for whatever reason. I am thinking there may be areas particularly in battery life but also in performance, accuracy or code design where one solution is better than the other.

**What I have done so far to answer this question**

My own evaluation so far from reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188643/thread-sleep-vs-timers) and `CountDownTimer`'s [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) are that since both are executed on the worker-thread, both have no ANR possibility. Both solutions will also gaurantee that one "update" will happen only after the previous update has finished. Unfortunately, this is all I have and hoping if anyone can help or guide me to an insightful and/or similar SO question I may have overlooked or was unsuccessful in finding.

I write this question a bit cautiously as I don't have a problematic code which requires debugging but I think this falls within [SO's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) category of a "specific programming problem", which hasn't been answered, and not included in the list of off-topic answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Calling Thread.sleep pauses the thread execution for a while where as countdown timer actually uses callbacks to notify timer expiry events and is asynchronous in nature.

2.If the thread execution pauses, you will not be able to use that specific thread for any other operation until the sleep timeout hence it is not recommended to use Thread.sleep approach. Obviously there is a load on cpu if it has to resume the thread execution and pause it.Where as in the case of countdown timer the thread continue to be in execution/idle state and as when events occur it fires to the respective listeners.

Answer (score 0):

```
call Thread.sleep() method is not good idea beacuse ii sleep the UI Thread and disadvantage of  CountDownTimer is, It Will stop when ur screen is off hence instead of this two try  Handler for that like this


 Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (dataReceived)
                {
                    cancelHandler();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    }

    public void cancelHandler()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```

Comment: please edit your answer to move the first paragraph outside the code section.